# Changing src with .attr() on an ng-repeat & ng-click not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have loaded pictures (pins) with an ng-repeat. When someone clicks on a colored pin, it will go grey, and vice-versa.

My ng-repeat is:  `ng-repeat="note in  vm.myData.contactHistoryContainer track by $index"`

```
  <!-- this is where the pin goes -->
  <div class="pin-container">
    <div ng-if="note.pinPush == false">
      <!-- unselected pin -->
      <img class="pin dark{{$index}}" src="app/assets/img/office-material.png" alt="uncolored pin" ng-click="vm.darkPinPress()">
    </div>
    <div ng-if="note.pinPush == true">
      <!-- selected pin -->
      <img class="pin colored{{$index}}" src="app/assets/img/office-material2.png" alt="colored pin" ng-click="vm.pinPress()">
    </div>
  </div>
```

The `ng-click` on those images goes to:

```
var lightpin = "app/assets/img/office-material2.png";
var darkpin = "app/assets/img/office-material.png";

            function darkPinPress() {
              console.log('dark pin pressed');
              $(this).attr('src', lightpin)
            }

            function pinPress() {
              console.log('colored pin was pressed---');
              $(this).attr('src', darkpin)
            }
```

Could someone please have a look and let me know where I am messing up? The `console.log`'s get triggered on both types of buttons

[image]

Comment: Check `$(this)` as in `console.log('pin pressed', $(this));` and see if it's as expected?

Comment: console.log('pin pressed', $(this)); returns the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use jQuery for your problem. I've made a plunker so you can se one way of overcoming your problem.
https://plnkr.co/edit/19H8KnyLpzdMbEPX4Oeq?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="note in vm.notes">
  <div ng-click="note.pinPush =  !note.pinPush">
    <div ng-if="note.pinPush">
      <img src="http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/179/4361592-picture.jpg" style="width:200px;">
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!note.pinPush">
      <img src="http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/180/4964551-picture.jpg" style="width:200px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the basic idea is to switch note.pinPush on every click. ng-if controls which picture to be shown.

**Edit: New plunker with click call to controller**

https://plnkr.co/edit/cRj0SoFWAawGbvCnu1Kv?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="note in vm.notes">
  <div ng-click="vm.noteClicked(note)">
    <div ng-if="note.pinPush">
      <img src="http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/179/4361592-picture.jpg" style="width:200px;">
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!note.pinPush">
      <img src="http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/180/4964551-picture.jpg" style="width:200px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The difference is the ng-click: `<div ng-click="vm.noteClicked(note)">`

Note:the src is a random picture

Comment: Thanks it seemed to work. now what if I need an ng-click to a function on the controller, to record which is the new pin

Comment: Se my plunker update. The note is given to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify doing this:

```
  <div class="pin-container">
    <div>
      <img ng-show="!enabled" src="app/assets/img/office-material.png" alt="uncolored pin" ng-click="enabled=!enabled">
      <img ng-show="enabled" src="app/assets/img/office-material2.png" alt="colored pin" ng-click="enabled=!enabled">
    </div>
  </div>
```

And, if you need call some function in controller you call it on ng-click method.

http://jsfiddle.net/MfHa6/1778/

Comment: Sorry, I dont really understand what you did there

Comment: You don't need write code behind code (js) to accomplish what you need.